# Facebook api using c#.net (OAuth Exception - #1)

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception

I am developing an app in .net framework using c# which integrate Facebook.

I have following requirements for my app

1. User can login to Facebook account
2. User can view Friends list, Messages & Notifications.

I successfully completed my 1 requirement. There is problem with 2 requirement which I shown below--

```
 public void Show_Friends()
    {
        try
        {
            fbclient = new FacebookClient("https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&amp;access_token=MyappId|MyAppSecret");
            dynamic friendslist = fbclient.Get("/me?fields=friendlists");//Here exception occours
            int numberOfFriends = (int)friendslist.data.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFriends; i++)
            {
                friendsListBox.Items.Add(friendslist.data[i].name);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Following exception occurs when I call Show_Friends method

> (OAuth Exception - #1) Bad Signature

Comment: You can only get friends that have granted uiser_friends permission to the app. So not all friends. There is no APIs for notications or messenges

Comment: @WizKid why the exception occurs? app has to show empty friend list

Comment: Does it matter? You can't get all friends. Or messages. Or notifications

Comment: @WizKid If some of my friends give the permission then the app has to access the granted friend list, so that exception matter

Comment: I would suggest that you read the Facebook documentation then on how to do Facebook Login

Comment: @WizKid already read that document and i successfully login, but there is no documentation on how to access friends list or any other services. If you have any other resources then please suggest me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115059/discussion-between-mohammad-adil-and-wizkid).

Comment: You FacebookClient call is totally wrong.

Comment: @WizKid Here[link] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens ) it shows how to get access token by using appid | secret code. So How FacebookClient Call is wrong?

Comment: No that is how you make a call to an endpoint using an access token. So read the documentation for how to do Facebook Login. Because what you are doing is totally wrong

Comment: `  public void Login()
        {
            string GoesTo = @"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
                            &client_id=MyId
                            &redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
                            &response_type=token
                            &scope=email
                            &display=popup";            

            
            brow.Navigate(GoesTo);
          
            
        }`
This is code of login into facebook account that i use in my app.